# Getting object value through loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a survey questions,

i am getting my object through angularjs http post

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

i am accessing data like this :`$data[0]->passObject->question_1`

for each questions i have write following :

```
if(!empty($data[0]->passObject->question_1)){
    if(!in_array(1, $ArrayQuestionsType)) {
        InsertUpdate(1,$data[0]->passObject->question_1,$ArrayQuestions,$data[0]->persinId);
    }
    else {InsertUpdate(1,(implode(',', json_decode(json_encode($data[0]->passObject->question_1), true))),$ArrayQuestions,$data[0]->persinId);}
}
```

for sixty questions i have to write sixty block like this,

is there any way to put single `if` statement mention above in a for loop
so that it change `$data[0]->passObject->question_1, $data[0]->passObject->question_2, $data[0]->passObject->question_3` etc? upto 60 times?

Comment: Send `question` as an array.

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables or properties with numeric suffixes like that, you probably should be using an array instead.

Comment: Couldnt you foreach $data[0]->passObject ?

Comment: is there any way to getting '$data[0]->passObject->question_1' to change questions number if i put those in for loop?  eg '$data[0]->passObject->question_1, $data[0]->passObject->question_2, $data[0]->passObject->question_3'

Comment: $data already an array, in that array passObject is another array object

Answer (score 0):

If you make a counting loop you can make "question_X" a variable

```
for($i=1;$i<=60;++$i){
$question="question_".$i;
$dataObject=$data[0]->passObject->$question;
}
```